# Docusign dynamic row generation in table

Tags: templates, dynamic, row, docusignapi

I have to dynamically generate the rows in Docusign template's table. Is there a way to achieve that ? I have to mention customer's detail which can vary from contract to contract and for that i don't want to keep static placeholders for that such that I preconfigure 100 rows and it will populate accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be solved using [tab](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/) from docusign official docs. Also please read examples [here](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-node-js-examples). API ref about [envelops](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/) will also helps you. Further demonstrations will be following.

```
function document1(args) {
  return (
    <div>
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{args.firstName}</td>
          <td>{args.lastName}</td>
          <td>{args.age}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

use that document into makeEnvelope function.

```
function makeEnvelope(args) {
      // create the envelope definition
      let env = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();
      env.emailSubject = "Please sign this document set";
    
      // add the documents
      let doc1 = new docusign.Document();
      let doc1b64 = Buffer.from(document1(args)).toString("base64");
      doc1.documentBase64 = doc1b64;
      doc1.name = "YOUR markup doc name";
      doc1.fileExtension = "html";
      doc1.documentId = "1";
    
      // The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
      env.documents = [doc1];
    
      // create a signer recipient to sign the document, identified by name and email
      // We're setting the parameters via the object constructor
      let signer1 = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
        email: args.signerEmail,
        name: args.signerName,
        recipientId: "1",
        routingOrder: "1",
      });
      // routingOrder (lower means earlier) determines the order of deliveries
      // to the recipients. Parallel routing order is supported by using the
      // same integer as the order for two or more recipients.
    
      // create a cc recipient to receive a copy of the documents, identified by name and email
      // We're setting the parameters via setters
      let cc1 = new docusign.CarbonCopy();
      cc1.email = args.ccEmail;
      cc1.name = args.ccName;
      cc1.routingOrder = "2";
      cc1.recipientId = "2";
    
      // Create signHere fields (also known as tabs) on the documents,
      // We're using anchor (autoPlace) positioning
      //
      // The DocuSign platform searches throughout your envelope's
      // documents for matching anchor strings. So the
      // signHere2 tab will be used in both document 2 and 3 since they
      // use the same anchor string for their "signer 1" tabs.
      let signHere1 = docusign.SignHere.constructFromObject({
          anchorString: "**signature_1**",
          anchorYOffset: "10",
          anchorUnits: "pixels",
          anchorXOffset: "20",
        }),
        signHere2 = docusign.SignHere.constructFromObject({
          anchorString: "/sn1/",
          anchorYOffset: "10",
          anchorUnits: "pixels",
          anchorXOffset: "20",
        });
      // Tabs are set per recipient / signer
      let signer1Tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
        signHereTabs: [signHere1, signHere2],
      });
      signer1.tabs = signer1Tabs;
    
      // Add the recipients to the envelope object
      let recipients = docusign.Recipients.constructFromObject({
        signers: [signer1],
        carbonCopies: [cc1],
      });
      env.recipients = recipients;
    
      // Request that the envelope be sent by setting |status| to "sent".
      // To request that the envelope be created as a draft, set to "created"
      env.status = args.status;
    
      return env;
    }
```

then make example worker function to use that envelope containing documents(either your table data or something else)

```
exampleSigningViaEmail.worker = async (args) => {
  // Data for this method
  // args.basePath
  // args.accessToken
  // args.accountId

  let dsApiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();
  dsApiClient.setBasePath(args.basePath);
  dsApiClient.addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + args.accessToken);
  let envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApiClient),
    results = null;

  // Step 1. Make the envelope request body
  let envelope = makeEnvelope(args.envelopeArgs);

  // Step 2. call Envelopes::create API method
  // Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
  results = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope(args.accountId, {
    envelopeDefinition: envelope,
  });
  let envelopeId = results.envelopeId;

  console.log(`Envelope was created. EnvelopeId ${envelopeId}`);
  return { envelopeId: envelopeId };
};
```